# Installing CentOS on VMware vCenter VM from remote console

Tags: centos, vmware-tools, vcenter

I have a VM on my school's VMware vSphere server and I need to install CentOS on it, the disc is already in it but I can't install it 'cause the console doesn't work without VMware Tools (I can't install them, the OS isn't installed).

Does anyone know how to install it?

Comment: From http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-whatis.html: "Using kickstart, a system administrator can create a single file containing the answers to all the questions that would normally be asked during a typical installation." So apparently you could make an ISO with a kickstart file on it and it would perform an automatic installation, similar to how preseeding works in Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vm console does not require vmware tools at all. If you cannot open console something is wrong. Check your vcenter and host logs to see if they have more details.